# What's the difference in shell between $(var), "$(var)", $((var)), ((condition)) etc?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm starting at shell script and I don't understand the difference between

`$(var), "$(var)", $(( var ))`

or just in conditionals. Like

```
while [ condition ] while (( condition)) or while (condition)
```

I have been searching in Google but nothing...

Comment: first result in google https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements/

Comment: Did you read your friendly shell manual? Look under parameter expansion, quoting and arithmetic expansion.

Comment: `[` is the name of a command. It's not syntax.

Comment: For fundamental questions like this, you would be well served by a bash tutorial. Here's one: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `$(var)` is command substutition -- it will execute the command named `var` and put the output into the current command. example:

   ```
   getent passwd $(whoami)
   ```
2. `"$(var)"` is the same as above, except thanks to the quotes, the command output will be substituted into the current command as a single word. Consider the difference between

   ```
   printf "%s\n" $(uname -a)
   ```

   and

   ```
   printf "%s\n" "$(uname -a)"
   ```
3. `$(( var ))` is arithmetic expansion where the arithmetic expression contained in the `var` variable is evaluated. Example:

   ```
   var='6*7'
   echo "$((var))"
   ```

In general, unless you need certain specific side-effects, always quote expansions: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

---

For `while` (and also `if`), the next part is a **command**. The conditional branching will be determined by the *exit status* of the command: 0 is "true", anything else is "false".

It so happens that `[` is an alias for the `test` command (with the proviso that the last argument to `[` must be `]`)

These 2 while loops are equivalent in their infinitude:

```
while true; do ...
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do
while [ $(id -u root) = "0" ]; do ...
```

Using single parentheses places the command pipeline following `while` into a subshell. Changes you make to the shell while in a subshell disappear when the subshell ends. For example, to loop while there are more than 10 files in /tmp, we could do:

```
while (cd /tmp; n=(*); [ "${#n[@]}" -gt 10 ]); do ...
```

When the subshell exits, the current directory is no longer /tmp and the variable n does not exist.

Double parentheses indicate an arithmetic expression:

```
while (( x * y < 100 )); do ...
```

Comment: And note that the spacing around the `[` and `]` really matters.

Comment: Exactly. A space is required because `[` is a *command*, and every command needs a space to separate it from its arguments